# Data getting lost in socket.io connection

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've a very primitive socket.io server written in nodejs. The code is as follows -

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var total = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('ping-android', function (msg) {
    console.log("Msg received from Android = " + msg);
  });

  socket.on('new-frame', function(msg) {
    console.log("frame received = " + msg.toString().length);
    total += msg.toString().length;
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('disconnected = ' + total);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And I've a client running locally on the same machine written in C++. I'm using the `socket.io-client-cpp`.

The relevant code is as follows -

```
h.socket()->emit("new-frame", std::make_shared<std::string>(buf, 100));
```

The only catch here is that the above code is called at very short intervals of time, probably 50-100 ms. Both server and the client are running locally.

When I print the length of the string received in the nodejs server, it is usually anything between 95-100.

How do I fix this? Or should I go with a whole different approach?

Comment: Fix what exactly?  If you're trying to receive binary data in socket.io, you have to do something special to tell it you want binary, not just treat it like a string.

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving binary data. Exactly what change do I have to make in the server? I looked at some examples and there was no special case for binary data. :/

Comment: I can't find a code example for receiving binary data, but I'm pretty sure you aren't getting an appropriate length by treating it as a string.  You probably have to somehow treat it as a buffer.  Also not sure whether you have to do something specific on the C++ side to send binary.

Comment: The C++ code is all fine at least.